# How to log an eventlog only when the script gives a red error?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

what i want to do is - log an event in the eventlog - application,
only when the scheduled script gives any red error in that session...

I know how to log it with Write-EventLog,
but cant limit it to only when it gives  a red error saying something maybe wrong.

your response is much appreciated!

Comment: You need to place your log writing into an if statement. Do you tried anything at this point?

Comment: yes, i know that, can u pls suggest on that if statement ur thinking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to clear `$Error` before your statemtent, then check if an error occurred:

```
$Error.Clear()
Invoke-Something
if ($Error.Count -gt 0) {
  Write-EventLog ...
}
```

Or you could turn all errors into [terminating errors](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/03/08/hey-scripting-guy-march-8-2010.aspx) and use a `try..catch` statement:

```
$eap = $ErrorActionPreference
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
try {
  Invoke-Something
} catch {
  Write-EventLog ...
}
$ErrorActionPreference = $eap
```

Comment: i dont think I understand these blocks clearly?!
one ques - what does this cmdlet 'Invoke-Something' does?

Comment: If you don't understand the answer then why did you accept it? Answers should only be accepted if they actually solve the problem described in the question (or at least contributed to the solution). As for `Invoke-Something`: that isn't an actual cmdlet, but a placeholder for whatever statement (or group of statements) you're running.

Comment: got everything working, thanks, u were of great help!